# Changes to page.php and single.php not applying

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm having quite a weird issue with my WordPress site. I am building a theme from scratch and I'm trying to make change to the containers on my blog page (page.php and single.php). Weirdly enough, I have made no major changes to the code other than add a wrapper, but the changes aren't showing up.

I've made many themes without this issue so I'm unsure what's going wrong this time. I have set the blog page to be the posts page in the settings so I can't understand why the template won't update. The code I have is below, and is just the standard WordPress code with the exception of `'grid wrapper'` and attempting to remove the sidebar which also shows.

I have done quite a bit of research on this to see what the problem could be, but sadly the only post similar was in 2014 with no answer.

```
<div class="container main-content">
    <div class="grid wrapper">
        <section class="the-content">


                <main>

                    <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
                    <?php while ( have_posts() ): the_post(); ?>
                        <?php get_template_part('template-parts/content', 'page'); ?>
                    <?php endwhile; // End of the loop. ?>

                </main>


        </section>
    </div>
</div>
```

Long story short, my content shows just fine. I just can't edit the wrapper which contains that content.

Comment: Maybe its a caching issue?

Comment: I did try emptying my cache on Chrome, I also tried loading this up on firefox. Nothing sadly

Comment: How does your file tree look like?

Comment: It's a brandnew WordPress site, so the filetree is as of an empty WordPress site. Only change is the homepage and blog pages have both been set in the settings.

Answer (score 0):

I would change parameters in `get_template_part()`

This is how it supposed to be used: [Understanding get_template_part](https://konstantin.blog/2013/get_template_part/)

So if you have blank Wordpress file structure, I'm not sure if you have template-parts for sure. You can have them only if you intentionally made them.

Comment: I have got template parts there already. This site is a standard boilerplate that I've used for all my sites, so its never not worked. The posts display themselves just  fine, I just can't edit the container around it.

Answer (score 0):

Use wordpress [Wp-Super_cache](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-super-cache/) Plugin

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Most likely index.php is overriding your file as in my case. It depends how your theme handles the loop so check out on your index.php and change it there.

Answer (score -1):

If i remember well, the blog page set in the back-office reference first at home.php and then index.php. Page and single aren't call.